# Swift Mocking Classes in XCTest

Tags: unit-testing, swift, xctest

I'm trying to mock a class in my test suite and getting **segmentation fault 11** error.

> 1. While silgen emitConstructor SIL function @_TFVSC20NSJSONReadingOptionsCfMS_FT_S_ for 'init' at

Here is a piece of code which makes Xcode crush my test suite:

```
func testSetup() {
    class MockEngine: Engine {
        var setupCoreDataCalled = false
        override func setupCoreData(){
            setupCoreDataCalled = true
        }
    }
    let me = MockEngine()
    me.setup()
    XCTAssertTrue(me.setupCoreDataCalled, "setupCoreData must be called at setup")
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it.
It's related to SwiftyJSON library.

here is more info: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/67